# Strong name signature not valid for this assembly devexpress.data.v20.1.dll

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress-windows-ui

I publish my application with Deploy method. But during installation popup error with log: "Strong name signature not valid for this assembly devexpress.data.v20.1.dll".

1. I tried this method.
   [https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t881415/strong-name-signature-not-valid-for-this-assembly-for-devexpress-data-v19-2-dll][1]
2. I tried all tips from stackoverflow(ClickOnce). But I can not found solution.
   I have a one way: I can export only Release/Debug folder. Applications in this folder are working.
   Before, I deploy my application to shared folder, and when user run app, app update itself. Now I need manually update app of every user.
   How correctly deploy app with devexpress components.

Comment: All the dlls from DevExpress are strongly signed, this shouldn't be an issue. Try to uninstall DX in install it aagin.

Comment: @MarkoJuvančič this question has no answere ? or has no any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

check all devexpress assembly on your Project

or use DevExpress Tool to export your assembly from

Visual studio =>Tools
Devexpress assembly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).